# Keep unique values of a column in a data frame WITHOUT using drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
excel1 user_id public_key  first_seen
0      Mark    key1        1/14/2015  11:51:41 PM
1      Mark    key2        1/14/2015  11:51:41 PM
2      Mark    key3        1/14/2015  11:51:41 PM
3      Rhonda  key4        2/16/2015  2:16:04 PM
4      Rhonda  key5        2/16/2015  2:16:04 PM
5      Rhonda  key6        2/16/2015  2:16:04 PM
```

I want to KEEP the rows but remove the duplicate entries in the `first_seen` column

```
excel1 user_id public_key  first_seen
0      Mark    key1        1/14/2015  11:51:41 PM
1      Mark    key2        
2      Mark    key3        
3      Rhonda  key4        2/16/2015  2:16:04 PM
4      Rhonda  key5        
5      Rhonda  key6
```

This is happening becuase I am doing a pd.merge on two csv files:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(output_df, read_df, left_on="user_id", right_on="user_id_left", how="inner").drop_duplicates(
        subset=['body'], keep='first')
```

I tried .filter() and .query() methods on the final dataframe but couldn't get the desired result. How can I get the desired df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['first_seen'] = df.drop_duplicates(['user_id', 'first_seen'])['first_seen']
```

Output:

```
   excel1 user_id public_key             first_seen
0       0    Mark       key1  1/14/2015 11:51:41 PM
1       1    Mark       key2                    NaN
2       2    Mark       key3                    NaN
3       3  Rhonda       key4   2/16/2015 2:16:04 PM
4       4  Rhonda       key5                    NaN
5       5  Rhonda       key6                    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Why have you used the user_id in the parameters?

Comment: Because I assume you only count `first_seen` duplicates within `user_id`. You can drop `user_id` if you want to look at duplicates across users.

Comment: Oh I see. So if I drop user_id it will drop all duplicate values from the column across users? Got it. Don't want that.